# Arduino Mega XBee Limited inputs

Tags: arduino-mega, xbee, wireless

I'm currently using an Arduino Uno with the Wireless SD shield with an XBEE attached so I can wirelessly send voltages from sensors to a computer. This works great but I am limited to 5 analog inputs. I am thinking of using a Mega but the Wireless SD Shield is the same for both models. Are there any shields/techniques were  I can wirelessly transmit up to 15 analog inputs to a PC using XBEE or otherwise,

Many Thanks,

AH

Comment: Why 5 inputs? The Uno has 6. (A0 to A5).

Comment: Sorry I meant 6!

Answer (score 0):

See [74HC4051 multiplexer / demultiplexer](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11976). That describes how you can use a multiplexer chip to multiplex analog inputs.

The 74HC4051 multiplexes 8 inputs into one, and the 74HC4067 multiplexes 16 inputs into one. Thus you would only use one analog input, plus 3 or 4 pins to tell the chip which input you want at a particular moment.

The general way a multiplexer works is like this:

[image: Multiplexer example]

By outputting a binary pattern to the A/B/C pins you select which input you want active at a particular moment. That is then copied to the output pin (pin 3 in this case). You would connect that to your analog port on the Arduino.

The code would rotate between each of the 8 pins (or 16 pins with the bigger chip), and then do an analogRead.

---

### Example wiring

[image: Connect 4051 chip to Arduino Uno]

---

### Example code

```C++
// Example of using the 74HC4051 multiplexer/demultiplexer

// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date:   14 March 2013

const byte sensor = A0;  // where the multiplexer in/out port is connected

const byte addressA = 5; // the multiplexer address select lines (A/B/C)
const byte addressB = 6;
const byte addressC = 7;

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Starting multiplexer test ...");
  pinMode (addressA, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (addressB, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (addressC, OUTPUT); 
  }  // end of setup

int readSensor (const byte which)
  {
  // select correct MUX channel
  digitalWrite (addressA, (which & 1) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite (addressB, (which & 2) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite (addressC, (which & 4) ? HIGH : LOW);
  // now read the sensor
  return analogRead (sensor);
  }  // end of readSensor

void loop ()
  {
  // show all 8 sensor readings
  for (byte i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
    Serial.print ("Sensor ");
    Serial.print (i);
    Serial.print (" reads: ");
    Serial.println (readSensor (i));
    }
  delay (1000);
  }  // end of loop
```

---

That only does 8 ports, but the 16-port chip would be conceptually similar.